# Django signals with shopify webhooks

Tags: python, django, shopify, webhooks, django-signals

I am new to Django signals and Shopify webhooks, but I want to implement this feature in to a project.

I am using [this package](https://github.com/discolabs/django-shopify-webhook), which also includes a set of WebhookSignals, to receive and verify the Shopify webhook, but then I want to do stuff with the information I receive (to be specific, I want to handle the customer information of an order and store it in a databse).

I believe I need to use the provided signals to do this, but I don't really understand how to. So far, I've tried to put a signals.py file in my project directory (together with settings.py) that looks the following:

```
from shopify_webhook.signals import orders_create

def my_callback(sender, **kwargs):
   print("Request finished!")

orders_create.connect(my_callback)
```

This obviously doesn't work, but how would I define a function that gets called whenever I receive a webhook from Shopify?

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I'd recommend just using the [`@webhook`](https://github.com/discolabs/django-shopify-webhook/blob/master/shopify_webhook/decorators.py#L14-L48) decorator directly on a view instead of unnecessarily complicating things with signals.

This is how your view would look:

```
from shopify_webhook.decorators import webhook
from myapp.models               import AuthAppShopUser

@webhook
def orders_create(request):
    user = AuthAppShopUser.objects.get(myshopify_domain=request.webhook_domain)
    order_data = request.webhook_data
    # The rest of your view here
```

The above example assumes that you're using [django-shopify-auth](https://github.com/discolabs/django-shopify-auth) for your user authentication, and have set up the user model `AuthAppShopUser` in accordance to its documentation. You'll also want to be sure that you've registered the view to a url pattern within your `urls.py`, and also registered the webhook to the store via the Shopify API.

Comment: Hi Julien, thank you very much, this is very helpful. This is my first time experimenting with webhooks as well and I need some assistance. 

I have two questions:

1) Is the django-shopify-webhook package still OK to use since the developer stopped development?
2) Where do I enter information with regard to the HMAC?

Lastly, I set up the above and all the requirements in my app. The webhook is triggered, but nothing happens, not even a print. What am I doing wrong?